# Responsive iframe not full height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm building a new website but ran into a small issue.
Everything is responsive so far except for the chat-iframe.
It just does not want to become 100% of the box height -.-
http://dev.kazuto.de/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the div with the class "video-container" height 100% for the iframe to get the right height you are looking for. Then you need to change the padding as it makes the chat to glide more than the container you want it to be.